# Autofill (autocomplete) not working on Email field in Safari

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple form with email address and submit button. Chrome autofills the email field but Safari doesn't. Any idea why?!

```
<form class="omb_loginForm" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control input-lg" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email address" value="{{ user_email or "" }}" autocomplete="on">
   <span class="help-block hidden">That email address doesn't look quite right.</span>
<input type="hidden" id="return_url" name='return_url' value="{{ return_url}}">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Send magic link</button>
</form>
```

Possibly relevant:

- there is sometimes another email form field on the page (for newsletter signup) but even when this is removed, it still doesn't work.
- I removed the `type="email"` and it worked in Safari ONCE but I can't replicate this.
- Another field elsewhere on the site (text search) also doesn't autofill in Safari, although it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I also, have same problem (on mobile Safari), you can try set autocomplete option to "email" (as described here [The HTML autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)), like so: `autocomplete="email"`. This option fixes (in my case) autocomplete of the phone field, but still not helps with autocomplete of the email field on mobile.